# Finding the dictionary keys whose values are numerically highest

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a Python `dict` of the form:

```
dict = {'Alice': 2341, 'Beth': 9102, 'Cecil': 3258, ......}
```

Is there an easy way to print the first x keys with the highest numeric values? That is, say:

```
Beth   9102
Cecil  3258
```

Currently this is my attempt:

```
max = 0
max_word = ""
for key, value in w.word_counts.iteritems():
    if value > max:
        if key not in stop_words:
            max = value
            max_word = key

print max_word
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Sort a dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: You might consider using a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead of a dictionary initially. Then you have `word_counts.most_common(x)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd simply sort the items by the second value and then pick the first K elements :

```
d_items = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: -x[1])
print d_items[:2]
[('Beth', 9102), ('Cecil', 3258)]
```

The complexity of this approach is `O(N log N + K)`, not that different from optimal `O(N + K log K)` (using QuickSelect and sorting just the first K elements).

Comment: Thanks. That works. Have no idea how or why, but none the less it works.

Comment: `d_items = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)`, the `reverse=True` kwarg is missing.

Comment: @brunsgaard: note the minus in the lambda function. That's exactly what `reverse=True` does for numeric keys, it's just a few characters shorter.

Comment: @Danstahr, doh, of cause... You are the boss of the python!, ignore my comment above.

Answer (score 5):

Using [`collections.Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = {'Alice': 2341, 'Beth': 9102, 'Cecil': 3258}
>>> c = Counter(d)
>>> c.most_common(2)
[('Beth', 9102), ('Cecil', 3258)]
```

It uses `sorted` (`O(n*log n)`), or `heapq.nlargest(k)` that might be faster than `sorted` if `k << n`, or `max()` if  `k==1`.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> (sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda x:x[1]))[:2]
[('Alice', 2341), ('Cecil', 3258)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
items = sorted(w.word_counts.items(), lambda x, y: cmp(x[1], y[1]), None, True) 
items[:5]
```

Replace 5 with the number of elements you want to get.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'Alice': 2341, 'Beth': 9102, 'Cecil': 3258}

vs = sorted(d, key=d.get,reverse=True)

l = [(x,d.get(x)) for x in vs[0:2]]
n [4]: l
Out[4]: [('Beth', 9102), ('Cecil', 3258)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert `dict` to list of tuples `[(2341, 'Alice'), ...]` then sort it (without `key=lambda ...`).